# angular material select (auto complete) via code insertion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material, dropdown

I have this markup:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Language</label>

    <md-select name="languageAndLocale" ng-model="$ctrl.voice.languageAndLocale" required>
        <md-option ng-value="language2" ng-repeat="language2 in $ctrl.languagesAndLocales">
            {{language2}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

and in my component i try to insert value to this field.

```
self.voice.languageAndLocale = "eng";
$scope.voiceForm.languageAndLocale = "eng";
```

How can I trigger autocomplete if I want to add just a prefix via code?

say the drop down contains `eng:en` and I set the field via code to be `eng` so I want it to be auto completed to `eng:en` as would have happened if i insert `eng` in the UI and no via code.

Comment: Where is your `matAutocomplete` stuff?

Comment: How can I trigger autocomplete if I want to add just a prefix via code?

Comment: Where is your matAutocomplete stuff?

Comment: This is not a md-autocomplete, this is a md-select. Please update the title.